# Ansible can't resolve EC2 tag if specified in static inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using Ansible to deploy to Amazon EC2, and I have ec2.py and ec2.ini set up such that I can retrieve a list of servers from Amazon. I have my server at AWS tagged `rvmdocker:production`, and `ansible all --list` returns my tag as `ec2_tag_rvmdocker_production.` I can also run:

```
ansible -m ping tag_rvmdocker_production`
```

and it works. But if I have that tag in a static inventory file, and run:

```
ansible all -m ping -i production
```

it returns:

```
tag_rvmdocker_production | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. Werecommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Here is my production inventory file:

```
[dockerservers]
tag_rvmdocker_production
```

It looks like Ansible can't resolve `tag_rvmdocker_production` when it's in the static inventory file.

**UPDATE**

I followed ydaetskcoR's advice and am now getting a new error message:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i production app.yml 
ERROR! ERROR! production:2: Section [dockerservers:children] includes undefined group: tag_rvmdocker_production
```

But I know the tag exists, and it seems like Ansible and ec2.py know it:

```
$ ansible tag_rvmdocker_production --list
  hosts (1):
    12.34.56.78
```

Here is my production inventory:

```
[dockerservers:children]
tag_rvmdocker_production
```

And my app.yml playbook file:

```
---
- name: Deploy RVM app to production
  hosts: dockerservers
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: true
  roles:
    - ec2
    - myapp
```

In the end, I'd love to be able to run the same playbook against development (a VM on my Mac), staging, or production, to start an environment. My thought was to have static inventory files that pointed to tags or groups on EC2. Am I even approaching this the right way?

Comment: What makes you think you can target instances by tag names in a static inventory file?

Comment: It looked in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#static-groups-of-dynamic-groups) like I could have a static inventory file with dynamic groups in it. I'm brand new to Ansible and EC2 though and have probably misunderstood it.

Comment: You've misunderstood. That example is showing 2 dynamic groups called `tag_Name_staging_foo` and `tag_Name_staging_bar` and then a static group called `staging` which contains both of the dynamic groups as children of the `staging` group. See [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables) for an example of groups of groups outside of dynamic inventories.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue to this, and resolved it as follows.

First, I created a folder to contain my inventory files, and put in there a symlink to my `/etc/ec2.ini`, a copy (or symlink) to the `ec2.py` script (with executable status), and a `hosts` file as follows.

```
$ ls amg-dev/*
amg-dev/ec2.ini -> /etc/ec2.ini
amg-dev/ec2.py
amg-dev/hosts
```

My EC2 instances are tagged with a `Type = amg_dev_web`

The hosts file contains the following information - the blank first entry is important here.

```
[tag_Type_amg_dev_web]

[webservers:children]
tag_Type_amg_dev_web

[all:children]
webservers
```

Then when I run `ansible-playbook` I specify the name of the folder *only* as the inventory which makes Ansible read the `hosts` file, and *execute* the `ec2.py` script to interrogate AWS.

```
ansible-playbook -i amg-dev/ playbook.yml
```

Inside my playbook, I refer to these as `webservers` as follows

```
- name: WEB | Install and configure relevant packages
  hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - common
    - web
```

Which seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, it looks like you've misunderstood the use of tags in a dynamic inventory.

The [AWS EC2 dynamic inventory script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) allows you to target groups of servers by a tag key/value combination. So to target your web servers you may have a tag called `Role` that in this case is set to `web` which you would then target as a dynamic group with `tag_Role_web`.

You can also have [static groups that contain children dynamic groups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#static-groups-of-dynamic-groups). This is much the same as how you use [groups of groups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables) normally in an inventory file that might be used like this:

```
[web-servers:children]
front-end-web-servers
php-web-servers

[front-end-web-servers]
www-web-1
www-web-2

[php-web-servers]
php-web-1
php-web-2
```

Which would allow you to generically target or set group variables for all of the web servers above simply by using the more generic `web-servers` group and then specifically configure the types of web servers using the more specific groups of either `front-end-web-servers` or `php-web-servers`.

However, if you put an entry under a group where it isn't defined as a child group then Ansible will assume that this is a host and will then attempt to connect to that host directly.

If you have a uniquely tagged instance that you are trying to reach via dynamic inventory then you simply use it as if it was a group (it just happens to currently only have one instance in it).

So if you want to target or set variables for the `dockerservers` group which then includes an instance that is tagged with the key-pair combination of `rvmdocker: production` then you would just do this:

```
[dockerservers:children]
tag_rvmdocker_production

[tag_rvmdocker_production]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is helpful context. I updated the question above--still not working, but different feedback from Ansible.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the final dynamic group definition in my example. As I mentioned in the rest of the example you just use it as a child group of a static group but you still need to define the empty group.

Comment: Still no good. I tried defining the empty group both above and below [dockerservers:children], no success. When I have it defined as in your example above, the error is:

    [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


    PLAY [Deploy RVM app to production]       ********************************************
    skipping: no hosts matched

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

Additional info: I'm running the Ansible scripts on my Mac, and I have a Boto config file with my AWS creds at ~/.boto.